# How do I receive an object from an objectInputStream and pass that object into a method

Tags: java, object, objectinputstream

I am stuck on a question with a university assignment and i need some help. We have to create a server-client program which has a UI with a basic form to input data, when the register button is clicked the form creates an object of the StudentDetails Class and sends it to the server class. The server class must receive the StudentDetails object and pass that object to a toDatabase class. The toDatabase class must accept the StudentDetails object and input the data into a database

I have done hours of research but i could only find out how to write the object from the objectInputStream to a file

StudentDetails Class

```
public class StudentDetails implements Serializable{
private String studentID;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String contactNum;
private String address;

//constructor
public StudentDetails(String studentID, String firstName, String lastName, String contactNum, String address) {
    this.studentID = studentID;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.contactNum = contactNum;
    this.address = address;
}
//getter for studentID
public String getStudentID(){
    return studentID;
}
//getter for firstName
public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}
//getter for lastName
public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}
//getter for contactNum
public String getContactNum(){
    return contactNum;
}
//getter for address
public String getAddress(){
    return address;
}
}
```

Client Class

```
public class Client extends javax.swing.JPanel {
//declaring the GUI components
private javax.swing.JFrame jFrameMain;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanelMain;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblStudentID;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblFirstName;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblLastName;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblContactNum;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblAddress;
private javax.swing.JTextField txfStudentID;
private javax.swing.JTextField txfFirstName;
private javax.swing.JTextField txfLastName;
private javax.swing.JTextField txfContactNum;
private javax.swing.JTextField txfAddress;
private javax.swing.JButton btnRegister;
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(6, 2);

public Client() throws IOException{
    createForm();
}

private void createForm() throws IOException{

    jFrameMain = new javax.swing.JFrame();
    jPanelMain = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    txfStudentID = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txfFirstName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txfLastName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txfContactNum = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txfAddress = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    lblStudentID = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblFirstName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblLastName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblContactNum = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblAddress = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    btnRegister = new javax.swing.JButton();

    //sets the panel to grid layout
    jPanelMain.setLayout(grid);

    //sets the lable text
    lblStudentID.setText("Student ID:");
    lblFirstName.setText("First Name:");
    lblLastName.setText("Last Name:");
    lblContactNum.setText("Contact Number:");
    lblAddress.setText("Address:");

    //sets the textfield text
    txfStudentID.setText("");
    txfFirstName.setText("");
    txfLastName.setText("");
    txfContactNum.setText("");
    txfAddress.setText("");

    //sets the button text
    btnRegister.setText("Register");

    //sets the JFrame size
    jFrameMain.setSize(300, 250);

    //sets the JFrames location
    jFrameMain.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    //adds the panel to the frame
    jFrameMain.add(jPanelMain);

    //adds the first rows components
    jPanelMain.add(lblStudentID);
    jPanelMain.add(txfStudentID);

    //adds the second rows components
    jPanelMain.add(lblFirstName);
    jPanelMain.add(txfFirstName);

    //adds the third rows components
    jPanelMain.add(lblLastName);
    jPanelMain.add(txfLastName);

    //adds the forth rows components
    jPanelMain.add(lblContactNum);
    jPanelMain.add(txfContactNum);

    //adds the fifth rows components
    jPanelMain.add(lblAddress);
    jPanelMain.add(txfAddress);

    //adds the last rows components
    jPanelMain.add("", this);//leves the grid empty
    jPanelMain.add(btnRegister);

    //button action listener
    btnRegister.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //vairiables to store the data from the textfield and trims the data 
            String studentID = txfStudentID.getText().trim();
            String firstName = txfFirstName.getText().trim();
            String lastName = txfLastName.getText().trim();
            String contactNum = txfContactNum.getText().trim();
            String address = txfAddress.getText().trim();

            //if tests that the textfields cannot be empty
            if(studentID.isEmpty()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jPanelMain, "Student ID cannot be empty");
            }
            else if(firstName.isEmpty()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jPanelMain, "First name cannot be empty");
            }
            else if(lastName.isEmpty()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jPanelMain, "Last Name cannot");
            }
            else if(contactNum.isEmpty()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jPanelMain, "Contact number cannot be empty");
            }
            else if(address.isEmpty()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jPanelMain, "Address cannot be empty");
            }
            else{
                try{

                    //apptempt connection to server
                    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",7777);

                    //Creates an output Stream
                    ObjectOutputStream toServer = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                    //creates an object of the studentDetails
                    StudentDetails studentDetails = new StudentDetails(studentID, firstName, lastName, contactNum, address);

                    //sends the studentDetails object to the server
                    toServer.writeObject(studentDetails);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jPanelMain, "Success");
                }
                catch (IOException exception){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jPanelMain, "Failed to connect to server");
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    });

    //sets the Frame visible
    jFrameMain.setVisible(true);
    jFrameMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(jFrameMain.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new Client();
}
}
```

Server Class

```
public class Server{
private ObjectOutputStream outputClient;
private ObjectInputStream inputClient;
private Object student;

public Server(){
    try{
        //create server socket
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7777);
        System.out.println("Server started");

        outputClient = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("student.dat",true));
        while(true){
            //listens for any new connection request
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            //create an input stream from the socket
            inputClient = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        }
    }
    //temporaily commented out catch
    //catch(ClassNotFoundException classEx){
        //classEx.printStackTrace();
    //}
    catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void toDatabase(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //database connection
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pihe2019","root","");

        //mysql insert statment
        String query = " insert into details (studenID, firstName, lastName, contactNum, address)" + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        //sql insert preparedstatment
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStmt.setString(1, "(StudenID from object DATA)");
        preparedStmt.setString(2, "(firstName from object DATA)");
        preparedStmt.setString(3, "(lastName from object DATA)");
        preparedStmt.setString(4, "(contactNum from object DATA)");
        preparedStmt.setString(5, "(address from object DATA)");

        //excute the prepared statment
        preparedStmt.execute();

        con.close();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException clEx){
      clEx.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlEx){
        sqlEx.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Server();

}
}
```

I Expect the result to be the data inserted into the database

Comment: You expect the object to be inserted in database - but what happens instead? I see no error here. What about API of [ObjectInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) confuses you?

Comment: I don't know how to pass the object that is received by the objectInput stream to the toDatabase() method, because the data that needs to be inserted in the database is stored in the studentDetails object

Comment: First of all, you need to call that method at least once. Presumably, after you received the object. Second, the method must be declared to accept parameters (right now it doesn't).

Comment: Could you possibly show how to pass the object to the toDatabase object in code form. I have edited the main method to call the toDatabase method

Comment: And since you've edited the method your code no longer compiles, right? You seem to be in need of a Java tutorial that would explain main concepts of the language to you. However, StackOverflow doesn't provide tutorials, you will need to search elsewhere for those.